# Spring-MVC: Return ResponseEnvelope

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Using Spring, how can I receive the following POST request properly so that I can return a result?

```
public ResponseEnvelope sendHalfMap(GameID gameID, PlayerID playerID) throws Exception
  {
    java.util.List<HalfMapNode> mapNodes = MapGenerator.generator();
    HalfMap halfMapMessageBody = new HalfMap(playerID.getID(), mapNodes);

    URL halfMapUrl = new URL(baseUrl, "game/" + gameID.getID() + "/halfmap");

    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
    ResponseEnvelope requestResult = (ResponseEnvelope)restTemplate.postForObject(halfMapUrl.toURI(), halfMapMessageBody, ResponseEnvelope.class);

    return requestResult;
  }
```

Comment: Is the `HalfMap` class one that you created or is it from another library? If it is one that you created, can you please post the source code for it?

Comment: @Justin Albano Thank you for taking a look. Inserted above.

Comment: Can you please also post the source code for `HalfMapNode`?

Comment: @JustinAlbano The editor does not let me post more code, but here is a link: https://pastebin.com/migpH79B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is seen in the exception message:

```
Main.NewMapNode does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

If the class `NewMapNode` does not have a default, no-argument constructor, the Spring MVC framework will not be able to create the JAXB context for the `NewMapNode` and therefore fails. If it not possible to create a default, no-argument constructor for that class, see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9268488/2403253) for how to create a customer `XmlAdapter`.

Comment: You are completely right, turns out I imported the wrong HalfMap implementation. Thanks!